# How to use React in Wordpress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-theming, frontity

I am creating Wordpress plugin. I am required to use React with it. How can I use it?
I have already tried to use React JS library using a script tag but it did not work for.

Comment: You got an answer already mentioning Frontity, but I've also been writing a Wordpress plugin in React lately, and I felt like Frontity was for developing the whole site and not just a plugin. I went another way: Using docker to running wordpress locally while developing, and building to a folder which is connected to the plugin folder in the wordpress container. You can check out my project here: https://github.com/WestCoastJitterbugsOrg/Personalized-Calendar/tree/main/client
Read the README, docker-compose.yml and webpack.wordpress-config.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Frontity](https://frontity.org/) or read [this](https://dev.to/julbrs/how-to-use-react-inside-a-wordpress-application-49i) article

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.